# Postgis 2: Polygon/MultiPolygon in a single column

Tags: postgis-2.0

Storing MultiPolygon and Polygon features in a single column used to be as simple as not creating or removing the geometry type check constraint.

Is there a similar simple fix in PostGIS 2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Say you have `my_table` with a `geom` column with a typmod `geometry(Polygon,4326)`:

```
CREATE table my_table(
  gid serial primary key,
  geom geometry(Polygon,4326)
);
```

To store whatever geometry type you want, just redefine the typmod to `geometry(Geometry,4326)`, or don't use typmods. (The former enforces the SRID, and the later doesn't enforce anything):

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE geometry(Geometry,4326);

INSERT INTO my_table(geom)
VALUES
  ('SRID=4326;POLYGON EMPTY'),
  ('SRID=4326;MULTIPOLYGON EMPTY');
```

However, the data in the `geometry_columns` view might not work with some applications, since it also says `'GEOMETRY'`.

Lastly, CHECK CONSTRAINTS can always be used with any table, as was the norm in PostGIS 1.5 and before. If you want to keep the table definitions as they were in 1.5, this is still supported.