# Determine which points are contained inside a given polygon

Tags: postgis, postgresql, polygon, sql, point-in-polygon

I have these database tables defined:

```
CREATE TABLE regions (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE region_points (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  region_id SERIAL REFERENCES regions (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  index INTEGER NOT NULL,
  point GEOMETRY(Point, 4326) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE stations (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
  point GEOMETRY(Point, 4326) NOT NULL
)
```

A `region` is a polygon, its points being defined in the `region_points` table. A `station` may reside at a single point somewhere *inside* a `region` polygon.

I'd like to write a **single** query that gets all `station`s inside a particular `region` polygon. At the moment, I don't know how, so I do it in multiple steps:

```
# 1. Get all points that comprise the region polygon.
SELECT point
FROM region_points
WHERE region_id = 1234
ORDER BY index

# 2. Programmatically (non-SQL) construct a linestring from the points. Not shown here.

# 3. Get all stations inside the polygon.
SELECT id, name, point
FROM (
    SELECT ST_GeomFromText($1, 4326) AS polygon
) AS query1, (
    SELECT id, name, point
    FROM stations
) AS query2
WHERE ST_Contains(query1.polygon, query2.point)
```

As you can see, I have to construct the linestring programmatically and then pass it into the query as an argument to `ST_GeomFromText`, because I don't know how to do it in SQL.

I don't want to do anything programmatically. How can I re-write all of this as one SQL query?

Comment: Why not to store the region as a polygon? If you need to work with the edge nodes like points, it's easier to extract them than to make the polygon anew for each query. See this question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/59403/12768

Answer (score 2):

I'd change my tables to something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE regions (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name text NOT NULL,
  geom geometry(Polygon,4326)
)

CREATE TABLE stations (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  region_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES regions (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  name text NOT NULL,
  point GEOMETRY(Point, 4326) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fk_reg FOREIGN KEY (region_id)
    REFERENCES regions (id) MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

Notes:

- you can use a polygon geometry
- text is prefered to varchar in 99% in PostgreSQL
- a foreign key is better than doing any spatial queries (about 1000x faster, more error-proof and less work)

If you just need to select stations in a region:

```
SELECT id, name, point
FROM stations 
WHERE region_id = 123;
```

Keep this structure if your goal is to have a useful database. Keeping points and making polygons in a query is like hunting ants with a tank - it's foolish unless you need the points much more often than the polygons (the questions suggest otherwise, but we don't know how much did you simplify the problem).

EDIT: If your don't know which station lies in which region, you can use some other tool (and save overhead with creating the database etc.), or you can compute it using PostGIS.

If you want to use PostGIS for this, then first step is to create and populate the `regions` table. If you have coordinates, make the polygons using WKT; if you have points somewhere in PostGIS, call [ST_MakePolygon](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePolygon.html). Or use [Nickves' answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/138712/12768) for this. Don't create extra table for points unless you already have it and too much other features depend on it. If the points are used about as much as the polygon, [ST_DumpPoints](http://www.postgis.org/documentation/manual-2.0/ST_DumpPoints.html) is your friend; extracting points should be faster than making a polygon.

The second step would be to prepare the `stations` table. The only difference from above is that you omit the NOT NULL for the first time (you can add it faster to make it clean). Create an AFTER INSERT trigger on Stations table calling following function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_region_id() RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
  IF NEW.region_id IS NULL THEN
    UPDATE stations
    SET regions_id = (
      SELECT id FROM region 
      WHERE ST_CONTAINS(region.geom, NEW.point)
    )
    WHERE id = NEW.id;
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then populate your stations table whatever way you want, leaving region_id NULL.

EDIT2: for the first time I misread your queries and thought you oversimplified things much more than you did. Sorry.

Comment: If I read the question right, the region_id that you use in your stations table is not known by now and spatial query is needed for finding that information.

Comment: Hunt ants with a tank. Rofl.

Comment: @user30184: answered by an edit.

Comment: @JohnBarça For this particular case yes, but is very common to  have a database with field measurmetns taken from a point, and the need for polygon came much later.

Comment: @nickves, sorry, I was making no commentary on the question/answer. I was amused by Pavel's use of that expression, as I have never heard it before. After 20 odd years in IT, I am familiar with changing requirements :D

Comment: no harm done, we are all friends here :D

Comment: @nickves: if such a situation occurs, it's easier and faster to change the geometry type than to compute the polygon for every query (I'm not sure about keeping both and using triggers to ensure consistency), unless you need the point-ness very often, or you must change really a lot of code. Perhaps the OP just oversimplified things for the question's sake, but keeping that table architecture reminded me a Monty Python sketch about hunting ants in a tank.

Comment: I have missed few details for the first time. I corrected it, made it little friendlier (and added few details), but kept the Monty Python reference so liked by @JohnBarça.

Comment: @PavelV. I have never seen that sketch before and I am English, so disgraceful oversight no my part. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

The general workflow to construct your polygon would be something like this: 
  `st_makepolygon(st_linefromMultipoint(st_collect(points.geom)))`

But you have to be aware that :

- your linestring has to be closed
- order of vertices does mater

a rudimary sql querry to create a polygon from a set of points would be the following:

```
with line as (
with mp as (
SELECT 
-- multipoint
ST_Collect(ARRAY[
ST_GeomFromText('POINT(1 2)'),
ST_GeomFromText('POINT(2 3)'),
ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-2 3.2)'),
ST_GeomFromText('POINT(0 0)')
]) as geom -- from point table where = [exrp] order by
)
select (ST_AddPoint( st_linefromMultipoint(mp.geom),ST_PointN(st_linefromMultipoint(mp.geom),1) )) as geom from mp
)
select st_makepolygon(line.geom) from line
```

Afterwards since you have constructed your polygon just wrap the above in your main query:

```
with polygon as (
-- above query 
)
select count(a.fid) from stations a, polygon b where st_contains(b.geom,a.point)
```

ofc it is very possible that your nodes in the region table do not follow an ordering at all you could use [ST_ConvexHull](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_ConvexHull.html) functions to 'simplify' the polygon creation:

```
with mp as (
SELECT 
-- multipoint mu
ST_Collect(ARRAY[
ST_GeomFromText('POINT(1 2)'),
ST_GeomFromText('POINT(2 3)'),
ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-2 3.2)'),
ST_GeomFromText('POINT(0 0)')
]) as geom -- from point table where = [exrp] order by
)
select st_convexhull(mp.geom) as geom from mp
```

Comment: after you have confirm that the querry that transforms points to polygon is to you liking it is very advisable to convert the query to function: region(region_id) - > region_polygon http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createfunction.html